# Error in Bluetooth Device Discovery

Tags: java, bluetooth, bluecove

I tried the following code for discovering a bluetooth device

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.bluetooth.DeviceClass;
import javax.bluetooth.DiscoveryAgent;
import javax.bluetooth.DiscoveryListener;
import javax.bluetooth.LocalDevice;
import javax.bluetooth.RemoteDevice;
import javax.bluetooth.ServiceRecord;
import javax.bluetooth.UUID;

/**
*
* Class that discovers all bluetooth devices in the neighbourhood,
*
* Connects to the chosen device and checks for the presence of OBEX push service in it.
* and displays their name and bluetooth address.
*
*
*/
public class BluetoothServiceDiscovery implements DiscoveryListener{

    //object used for waiting
    private static Object lock=new Object();

    //vector containing the devices discovered
    private static Vector vecDevices=new Vector();

    private static String connectionURL=null;


    /**
     * Entry point.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BluetoothServiceDiscovery bluetoothServiceDiscovery=new BluetoothServiceDiscovery();

        //display local device address and name
        LocalDevice localDevice = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
        System.out.println("Address: "+localDevice.getBluetoothAddress());
        System.out.println("Name: "+localDevice.getFriendlyName());

        //find devices
        DiscoveryAgent agent = localDevice.getDiscoveryAgent();

        System.out.println("Starting device inquiry...");
        agent.startInquiry(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC, bluetoothServiceDiscovery);

        try {
            synchronized(lock){
                lock.wait();
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        System.out.println("Device Inquiry Completed. ");

        //print all devices in vecDevices
        int deviceCount=vecDevices.size();

        if(deviceCount <= 0){
            System.out.println("No Devices Found .");
        }
        else{
            //print bluetooth device addresses and names in the format [ No. address (name) ]
            System.out.println("Bluetooth Devices: ");
            for (int i = 0; i <deviceCount; i++) {
                RemoteDevice remoteDevice=(RemoteDevice)vecDevices.elementAt(i);
                System.out.println((i+1)+". "+remoteDevice.getBluetoothAddress()+" ("+remoteDevice.getFriendlyName(true)+")");
            }
        }

        System.out.print("Choose the device to search for Obex Push service : ");
        BufferedReader bReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String chosenIndex=bReader.readLine();
        int index=Integer.parseInt(chosenIndex.trim());

        //check for obex service
        RemoteDevice remoteDevice=(RemoteDevice)vecDevices.elementAt(index-1);
        UUID[] uuidSet = new UUID[1];
        uuidSet[0]=new UUID("1105",true);

        System.out.println("\nSearching for service...");
        agent.searchServices(null,uuidSet,remoteDevice,bluetoothServiceDiscovery);

        try {
            synchronized(lock){
                lock.wait();
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(connectionURL==null){
            System.out.println("Device does not support Object Push.");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Device supports Object Push.");
        }
    }


    /**
     * Called when a bluetooth device is discovered.
     * Used for device search.
     */
    public void deviceDiscovered(RemoteDevice btDevice, DeviceClass cod) {
        //add the device to the vector
        if(!vecDevices.contains(btDevice)){
            vecDevices.addElement(btDevice);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Called when a bluetooth service is discovered.
     * Used for service search.
     */
    public void servicesDiscovered(int transID, ServiceRecord[] servRecord) {
        if(servRecord!=null && servRecord.length>0){
            connectionURL=servRecord[0].getConnectionURL(0,false);
        }
        synchronized(lock){
            lock.notify();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Called when the service search is over.
     */
    public void serviceSearchCompleted(int transID, int respCode) {
        synchronized(lock){
            lock.notify();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Called when the device search is over.
     */
    public void inquiryCompleted(int discType) {
        synchronized(lock){
            lock.notify();
        }

    }//end method


}//end class
```

but got the following error:

```
Native Library intelbth_x64 not available
Native Library bluecove_x64 not available
Exception in thread "main" javax.bluetooth.BluetoothStateException: BlueCove libraries not available
    at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl.createDetectorOnWindows(BlueCoveImpl.java:896)
    at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl.detectStack(BlueCoveImpl.java:439)
    at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl.access$500(BlueCoveImpl.java:65)
    at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl$1.run(BlueCoveImpl.java:1020)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl.detectStackPrivileged(BlueCoveImpl.java:1018)
    at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl.getBluetoothStack(BlueCoveImpl.java:1011)
    at javax.bluetooth.LocalDevice.getLocalDeviceInstance(LocalDevice.java:75)
    at javax.bluetooth.LocalDevice.getLocalDevice(LocalDevice.java:95)
    at BluetoothServiceDiscovery.main(BluetoothServiceDiscovery.java:42)
```

while coding in eclipse. I am using bluecove 2.1.0 and a 64-bit version of Windows 8.

Can anyone please suggest me a fix?

Comment: which version of win 8 are you using? 32/64 bit?

Comment: I am using 64-bit Windows 8, and my Eclipse version was 64-bit too.

Comment: then use that bluecove library 64-bit version..

Comment: I tried it, didn't work. I saw on some blog (sorry, no link to support) that there are currently some issues with the 64-bit version.

Answer (score 13):

these two links helped me a lot

this is compatible 64bits

http://snapshot.bluecove.org/distribution/download/2.1.1-SNAPSHOT/2.1.1-SNAPSHOT.62/

documentation

http://www.jsr82.com/jsr-82-initialization-localdevice/

Comment: For the same version 2.1.1 of bluecove, some releases include native libraries while others dont. I had received a project with a .jar file shipped without native libraries, so redownloading and copying over the new .jar file solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

There is even a newer version: http://snapshot.bluecove.org/distribution/download/2.1.1-SNAPSHOT/2.1.1-SNAPSHOT.63/

Also, it's important to note that this *replaces* any other bluecove jar.  Because the message indicated missing libraries, I initially *added* this, and it caused a version conflict.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the JAR you have added does not contains x64 dll. Download the JAR from the below link and use it. It worked for me.
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/b/Downloadbluecove211jar.htm