# Bluecove intelbth_x64 and bluecove_x64 not available when generating jar file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, bluetooth, bluecove

I'm using Intellij to work on a JavaFX application that uses the `BlueCove 2.1.0` library. It works perfectly fine when compiling with the IDE but for some reason, when building the artifact with dependencies and then running it, I get this Exception :

```
Native Library bluecove_x64 not available

javax.bluetooth.BluetoothStateException: BlueCove libraries not available
    at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl.createDetectorOnWindows(BlueCoveImpl.java:896)
    at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl.detectStack(BlueCoveImpl.java:439)
    at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl.access$500(BlueCoveImpl.java:65)
    at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl$1.run(BlueCoveImpl.java:1020)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl.detectStackPrivileged(BlueCoveImpl.java:1018)
    at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl.getBluetoothStack(BlueCoveImpl.java:1011)
    at javax.bluetooth.LocalDevice.getLocalDeviceInstance(LocalDevice.java:75)
    at javax.bluetooth.LocalDevice.getLocalDevice(LocalDevice.java:95)
    at mbe.td2015.projectqanda.WaitThread.waitForConnection(WaitThread.java:62)
    at mbe.td2015.projectqanda.WaitThread.run(WaitThread.java:44)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: This might help someone in the future.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16886146/error-in-bluetooth-device-discovery